# Difficulty with getting TLS 1.2 to work with cURL

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am having difficulty curling an HTTPS url that uses TLS 1.2, in my curl operation- I post my login data into the website and save it in cookiefile. The error message I am getting is this:

"API Error:SSL connect error"

I have tried setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST)` to 6 but that does not seem to work, any suggestions?

Versions I am using:

OpenSSL version is 1.0.2b
CURL version is 7.49.1
PHP is 5.5
Here is the code:

```
    public function curl_request($url, $data, $method = 'GET', $headers = array(), $ssl_verify = false)
    {
            $ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, $ssl_verify);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, $ssl_verify);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES, range(400, 599));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);


            if ($method == 'POST')
            {
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 6);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }

            $resp  = curl_exec($ch);      

            if(curl_errno($ch))
            {
                    throw new Exception('Unleashed API Error:' . curl_error($ch));
            }

            //print("<pre>" . print_r($resp, true). "</pre>")

            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            $output = array();
            $output['resp'] = $resp;
            $output['info'] = $info;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TLS 1.2 not working in cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145089/tls-1-2-not-working-in-curl)

Comment: $ssl_verify is true or false?

Comment: $ssl_verify = false

Answer (score 0):

> OpenSSL version is 0.9.8b

There is no support for TLS 1.2 in OpenSSL 0.9.8. You need at least OpenSSL version 1.0.1.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated the OpenSSL, should that have resolved the issue or is there something else I've missed?

Comment: @Marcin: if you not only updated the OpenSSL binary but also curl so that it uses this library then at least the problem if no support for TLS 1.2 should be resolved.